# Web scraping of masked URL using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, dom, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

I want to scrape some stock data from a website https://dps.psx.com.pk/ using VBA in Excel, but the problem is the URL of this website does not change.

When I click on market summary as highlighted in image#1
[Image#1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdINj.png)

that will return the whole market summary, I just need to scrape data in Excel using VBA as highlighted in the image#2.
[Image#2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mE04n.png)

I tried to examine the network with fiddler as shown in image#3
[Image#3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFjrc.png)

and develop the following code in VBA.

```html
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    ' Add references
    ' Microsoft HTML Object Library
    ' Microsoft XML, v6.0

    Dim sResp As String
    Dim rOutputCell As Range
    Dim oElememnt
    Dim cElements As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim oTableRow
    Dim oTableCell



    ' Retrieve HTML from website
    With New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
        ' Send request
        .Open "GET", "https://dps.psx.com.pk/webpages/mktSummary.php?r=REG", True
        Do Until .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
        sResp = .ResponseText
    End With
    
    
    ' Parse response and output
    With New HTMLDocument
        ' Load response HTML into DOM
        .body.innerHTML = sResp
        ' Clear first worksheet for output
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells.Delete
        
        Set rOutputCell = Cells(3, 1)
        Set oElememnt = .getElementsByClassName("tableHead")(0)
        For Each oTableRow In oElememnt.getElementsByTagName("tr")
            For Each oTableCell In oTableRow.getElementsByTagName("td")
                rOutputCell.Value = oTableCell.innerText
                Set rOutputCell = rOutputCell.Offset(0, 1)
            Next
            Set rOutputCell = rOutputCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Cells(1, 1)
        Next
    
      End With

    MsgBox "Completed"

End Sub
```

But when I run this code it just shows running but nothing happens even after waiting for sometime. I don't know whether it got stuck in Event Loop or some other problem is there please help.

Comment: Did you look at the requests being made when you search for "EFOODS"?

Comment: This is basic web scraping. You need to inspect the source code elements and like @antfuentes87 says , follow the requests. It sounds more like you need to purchase a third party tool to help you. It's also called "scrape" and "scraping"

Comment: In VB editor add a breakpoint at the line e. g. `Set rOutputCell = Cells(3, 1)`, run the code, when it stops at the breakpoint, begin to step into line by line, checking values of variables in the locals window. First of all check `oElememnt`, `oTableRow`, `oTableCell`. You should make sure that `.getElementsByClassName("tableHead")` returns not empty collection, and that `tableHead` is relevant here.

Answer (score 3):

All the necessary info to scrape that data you may find in captured by Fiddler request which is logged after you made an input of the quote symbol in a browser manual:

[image: fiddler]

You need to reproduce that request via VBA and parse HTML response. There is the example showing how that might be done:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    ' Add references
    ' Microsoft HTML Object Library
    ' Microsoft XML, v6.0

    Dim sResp As String
    Dim rOutputCell As Range
    Dim oElememnt
    Dim cElements As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim oTableRow
    Dim oTableCell

    ' Retrieve HTML from website
    With New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
        ' Send request
        .Open "POST", "https://dps.psx.com.pk/webpages/SL_main_page.php", True
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .Send "symbolCode=EFOODS"
        Do Until .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
        sResp = .ResponseText
    End With
    ' Parse response and output
    With New HTMLDocument
        ' Load response HTML into DOM
        .body.innerHTML = sResp
        ' Clear first worksheet for output
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells.Delete
        ' Parse SL_cmpInfo table and output
        Set rOutputCell = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1)
        Set oElememnt = .getElementsByClassName("SL_cmpText")(0)
        rOutputCell.Value = oElememnt.innerText
        ' Parse SL_mktStats1 tables and output
        Set rOutputCell = Cells(3, 1)
        Set cElements = .getElementsByClassName("SL_mktStats1")
        For Each oElememnt In Array(cElements(1), cElements(2), cElements(3))
            For Each oTableRow In oElememnt.getElementsByTagName("tr")
                For Each oTableCell In oTableRow.getElementsByTagName("td")
                    rOutputCell.Value = oTableCell.innerText
                    Set rOutputCell = rOutputCell.Offset(0, 1)
                Next
                Set rOutputCell = rOutputCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Cells(1, 1)
            Next
        Next
        ' Parse SL_announce table and output
        Set rOutputCell = rOutputCell.Offset(1, 0)
        Set oElememnt = .getElementsByClassName("SL_announce")(0)
        For Each oTableRow In oElememnt.getElementsByTagName("tr")
            For Each oTableCell In oTableRow.getElementsByTagName("td")
                rOutputCell.Value = oTableCell.innerText
                Set rOutputCell = rOutputCell.Offset(0, 1)
            Next
            Set rOutputCell = rOutputCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Cells(1, 1)
        Next
    End With
    MsgBox "Completed"

End Sub
```

Don't forget to add the necessary references:

[image: refs]

The output for me is as follows:

[image: output]

As required:

[image: requirement]

Comment: How do you know if you need to include cookie information please?

Comment: @QHarr MSXML2.XMLHTTP supports cookies processing, and automatically adds the necessary cookies to requests. You can find that from fiddler capture.

Comment: Many thanks for getting back to me. Can't upvote again, but if I could I would.

Comment: @QHarr Find more tips here [WinINet vs. WinHTTP (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh227298(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @omegastripes Thank you so much . It works perfectly for me. Can you tell me what is the best way to learn VBA ?

Comment: @FaizanNauman I would suggest to start from practice and studying Application object model.

Comment: @omegastripes I have edited my question, please advice on this one. Your previous answer was remarkable so I just got stuck in this . Please help in this one I have very high hopes from you.

Comment: @FaizanNauman For further insight, please try to examine requests with Fiddler or with browser developer tools network tab, then build your own code based on my answer. After you made some effort and got stuck - edit the question, and post all stuff you have (Fiddler capture images, VBA code, etc.) with description what's wrong.

Comment: @omegastripes I tried to work on your code using fiddler but it is not working. Please check my edited question.

Comment: Nice. So much faster than IE.