# Stop IE from loading further when required data is there

Tags: html, excel, internet-explorer, vba

I'm trying to stop `IE` when the required data has already shown up because otherwise it just keeps loading even when I can see everything on `.Visible=True`.

I want to pass some kind of variant (`SOMETHING`) to my web page loading `sub` and it would test an `IHTMLElement` accordingly.

I've realised that I cannot pre-define an `IHTMLElement` and pass it before loading the page. Was googling around but couldn't find any solutions. Currently this is beyond my knowledge and I wanna figure out how to do this.

```
Private ie_browser As InternetExplorer

Private Sub Download_Test()

   Dim str_url As String
   str_url = "..."
   Set ie_browser = New InternetExplorer
   ie_browser.Visible = True

   'here I want pass that spec variant to the Sub
   Call Load_WebPage(str_url, SOMETHING)

End Sub

Private Sub Load_WebPage( _
   ByVal str_url As String, _
   ByVal SOMETHING _
   )

   Dim html_data_element As IHTMLElement
   Dim int_counter_sleep As Integer

   ie_browser.Navigate str_url
   For int_counter_sleep = 1 To 60     '60 x 500 = 30000 ms = 30 sec
      If ie_browser.Busy Or ie_browser.READYSTATE <> 4 Then

         'SOMETHING -> html_data_element
         'here I want to use that spec variant to define said IHTMLElement

         If Not html_data_element Is Nothing Then
            ie_browser.Stop
            Exit For
         End If

         Sleep 500
      Else
         Exit For
      End If
   Next int_counter_sleep

End Sub
```

Comment: Just a note: `Dim str_url, str_html_innertext As String` will define `str_url As Variant` which is default if no type is specified. You need to specify a type for **every** variable `Dim str_url As String, str_html_innertext As String`

Comment: omg... thx for the heads up!

Comment: You may opt to `XMLHTTP`+`HTMLDocument` if the webpage source contains the necessary data itself. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51125552/2165759).

Comment: Huh, that's on an other level for me right now, but I guess I will have to dig into it sooner or later.

Comment: Was there an URL that demonstrated this issue you could share?

Comment: Here you go: [link](http://tdcfinancial.ttweb.net/Default.aspx?action=securityDetails&id=tts-898974&menuId=1_4_4&lang=hu&pathName=S%26P%20500)
IE 11, security level: 4th

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After learning for a few hours I've managed to solve the problem with an additional function where I reference it by name and use `Application.Run`to execute it.

```
Private ie_browser As InternetExplorer

Private Sub Download_Test()
    Dim str_url As String
    str_url = "..."
    Set ie_browser = New InternetExplorer
    ie_browser.Visible = True
    Load_WebPage str_url, "Get_webpage_readiness"   'passing only the name of the function
End Sub

Private Sub Load_WebPage( _
    ByVal str_url As String, _
    Optional ByVal str_get_readiness_function_name As String _
    )
    Dim int_counter_sleep As Integer
    Dim bool_readiness As Boolean
    ie_browser.Navigate str_url
    For int_counter_sleep = 1 To 60
        If ie_browser.Busy Or ie_browser.READYSTATE <> 4 Then

            'Referencing the function by name
            If str_get_readiness_function_name <> vbNullString Then
                bool_readiness = Application.Run(str_get_readiness_function_name)
                If bool_readiness Then
                    ie_browser.Stop
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If

            Sleep 500
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next int_counter_sleep
End Sub

Private Function Get_webpage_readiness() As Boolean
    Dim html_data_element As IHTMLElement
    On Error Resume Next    'skipping the error while the webpage hasn't loaded yet
    Get_webpage_readiness = False
    Set html_data_element = ie_browser.Document. ...
    If Not html_data_element Is Nothing Then
        Get_webpage_readiness = True
    End If
End Function
```