# How to extract web data in Visual Basic for Applications using XML HTTP requests?

Tags: excel, vba, dom, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

> Version: Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications 7.1

I'm working on a small scale data mining/ web data extraction personal project. My question is about data extraction, though.

Extracting data from a web page using IE works but runs very slowly, and for this reason I'm leaning towards the use of XML HTTP requests. However, when I tried it on a website that I plan to work on, I couldn't extract the data that I need except for some static contents. Upon examining the response text, I found out that it does not contain the data that I need. Probably it is generated by JavaScript or similar technologies. I'm not sure if these scripts are rendered in VBA using XML HTTP requests just like in web browsers.

Also, interesting to note here is upon examining the web page from the Developer Tools > Network, it provides a [Request URL](https://www.pse.com.ph/stockMarket/companyInfo.html?method=fetchHeaderData&ajax=true) in which the response contains most of the data that I need but it is in JSON format. I don't know how to parse it but I just provided this information so you may point me at the right direction just in case extracting data from a dynamic web page using XML HTTP request is not possible.

I hope you can spend a couple of minutes to see my code and where I might have done it incorrectly.

Thank you all very much. I'd really appreciate your help.

Here's the basic idea of what I'm trying to do:

**With XML (Unable to extract the data needed):**

```
Option Explicit

Sub dataMinExProject_XML()

    Dim xmlPage As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim htmlDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim coName As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim secSym As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim closePrice As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim URL As String
    
    URL = "https://www.pse.com.ph/stockMarket/companyInfo.html?id=260&security=468&tab=0"
    
    Set xmlPage = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    With xmlPage
        .Open "POST", URL, False
        .send
    End With
    
    Do Until xmlPage.ReadyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
    Set htmlDoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    htmlDoc.body.innerHTML = xmlPage.responseText
    
    Set coName = htmlDoc.getElementById("comTopInfoHead").Children(0)
    Set secSym = htmlDoc.getElementById("secSymbol")
    Set closePrice = htmlDoc.getElementById("headerLastTradePrice")
    
    Debug.Print "Company Name: ", """" & coName.innerText & """"
    Debug.Print "Security Symbol: ", """" & secSym.innerText & """"
    Debug.Print "Closing Price: ", """" & closePrice.innerText & """"
    
    xmlPage.abort
    Set xmlPage = Nothing
    MsgBox ("alright!")
    
End Sub
```

---

```
Immediate Window

Company Name:               "BDO Unibank, Inc."
Security Symbol:            ""
Closing Price:              "  "
```

Upon examining the Immediate Window, it shows that the `Security Symbol` and the `Closing Price` were not extracted.

Just for comparison, and to prove that the data to be extracted exists, I also provided my code here that uses an instance of IE.

**With IE (Data extracted but runs relatively slow):**

```
Option Explicit

Sub dataMinExProject_IE()

    Dim ieApp As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim htmlDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim coName As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim secSym As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim closePrice As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim URL As String
    
    URL = "https://www.pse.com.ph/stockMarket/companyInfo.html?id=260&security=468&tab=0"
    
    Set ieApp = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    With ieApp
        .Navigate (URL)
        .Visible = vbTrue
    End With
    
    Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
    Set htmlDoc = ieApp.Document
    
    Set coName = htmlDoc.getElementById("comTopInfoHead").Children(0)
    Set secSym = htmlDoc.getElementById("secSymbol")
    Set closePrice = htmlDoc.getElementById("headerLastTradePrice")
    
    Do Until secSym.innerText <> vbNullString And closePrice.innerText <> vbNullString
        Loop
    DoEvents
    
    Debug.Print "Company Name: ", """" & coName.innerText & """"
    Debug.Print "Security Symbol: ", """" & secSym.innerText & """"
    Debug.Print "Closing Price: ", """" & closePrice.innerText & """"
    
    ieApp.Quit
    Set ieApp = Nothing
    MsgBox ("alright!")
    
End Sub
```

---

```
Immediate Window

Company Name:               "BDO Unibank, Inc."
Security Symbol:            "BDO"
Closing Price:              "130.50"
```

Looking at the Immediate Window, it shows that it successfully extracted the data. However, as I've stated earlier, its poor performance made me look at other options..

> References:
>
> [Web Scraping of Masked URL Using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51124993/web-scrapping-of-masked-url-using-vba/51125552#51125552)

Comment: For the JSON issue see  [(c) Tim Hall's JSON Converter for VBA](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, thank you very much for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Working with HTTP requests is the way to go. As you said IE is slow and inefficient.

Once you have located the request that returns the data you are interested in as a response, your work is relatively easy and it will most probably involve one of the following:

1. The request returns an html page as a response. In that case you should use the `Microsoft HTML Object Library`, assign the response HTML to an `HTMLDocument` and parse the object using the existing methods. For that you'll need a reference to `Microsoft HTML Object Library`.
2. The request returns a `JSON` string. In that case you can store the response in a string variable and parse it to a json object using [VBA JSON](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON). The instructions and the examples given in the link are very informative. Use an online JSON viewer to understand the response's structure and you'll be able to extract any piece of information you want. For that you'll need a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` as well as the  `VBA JSON` module of course.
3. A combination of the two. For example some requests might return an HTML page as a response which contains the data in JSON format. Others could return a JSON string and one of the items contained in it could be an HTML table for example. In this case a combination of the above workflows will do the trick.

As far as the request itself is concerned, make sure you use the headers that are essential to the request. The header `Content-Type:` is one of them and it's essential to `POST` request. You can use the `.setRequestHeader` method. The request's body which contains the parameters of the request, is also essential. I suggest you use `WinHTTP Services, version 5.1` for your requests.

Once you've mastered these, you'll gain complete control over the data you want to retrieve.

Comment: I've seen from other codes that they include `.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` in their requests. What does it do?

Answer (score 0):

There are a set of [APIs](http://www.pseapi.com/). Currently the Stock API endpoint doesn't seem to be working. I have raised an issue. Should it be working again you can use the following syntax. The json parser is [jsonconverter.bas](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON). You add the .bas to your project and go VBE > tools > References > Add reference to Microsoft Scripting runtime

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub dataMinExProject_XML()
    Dim xmlPage As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, aDate As String, symbol As String, json As Object, url As String
    Set xmlPage = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    aDate = Format$(Date - 1, "MM-DD-YYYY")
    symbol = "JFC"
    url = "http://pseapi.com/api/Stock/" & symbol & "/" & aDate

    With xmlPage
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .send
        Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
    End With
End Sub
```

It returns a dictionary object which you can parse out info by key

```
{
    "symbol":"JFC",
    "date":"15/03/2017",
    "open":197.0000,
    "high":197.4000,
    "low":195.0000,
    "close":196.0000,
    "bid":195.5000,
    "ask":196.0000,
    "volume":141740,
    "value":27747934.0000,
    "netForeign":-6464136.0000
}
```

So, for my example:

```
Dim key As  Variant
For Each key In json.keys
    Debug.Print key, json(key)
Next
```

Comment: Is there any way to get it done using only built-in libraries, or at least widely-used third-party tools? I'm in for the long term solution. I'm afraid that if I use third-party tools and APIs with low user base , chances are high that it is not routinely maintained and it might break on the next update. If it breaks, then my code breaks. I like the idea of open-source tools for other personal projects, just not on this one because the integrity of the data is really important in financial computing.

Comment: The XHR target you mentioned seems to have a security measure in place which simply mimicking headers and passing cookies from a prior GET request don't get around. I tried passing JSESSIONID , adding headers and passing the correct body in the POST but still get a 403 forbidden. Perhaps someone else can work out how to get around that. I think the site in general is designed to prevent easy scraping - worth checking terms and conditions. Your IE code is good with some scope for improvement but nothing that would dramatically increase performance. What is slow when  you refer to too slow?

Comment: Yes, I just found out few minutes ago when I tried to use that XMLHTTPReq URL and examine the response text, it returned "Access Denied". But in developer tools preview, the data is visible as JSON format. As with terms and conditions of the site, from a perspective of a non-lawyer like me, it's very vague. Well, if it is not possible to use XHR, I'll just implement it using IE and HTML objects. Probably, I'll use arrays and opening several instances of IE at once so other loads while processing the others. Is that a bad idea? I don't know because I don't really have a background in CS..

Comment: Oh, wow! "..few other languages" with no CS background aside from being a vet. Sometimes the world is not fair. I envy people like you who seems to learn complex subjects with ease. Well, thank you very much, Doc, for helping a struggling amateur and newbie programmer. I really appreciate it. I hope you can unlock the mystery of this ajax thing. I'm looking forward to it..

Comment: I'm hoping user SIM or Omegastripes will see this and have a go. I'm  a relative noob poking around Python and R currently. Definitely liking Python for web-scraping.  And trust me - I often feel like I am banging my head against subject matter.

Comment: omegastripes responded to my email, he provided a code that has two subroutines but is not complete yet as he's still trying to solve `WinHttp Runtime Error -2147012739 (80072f7d) "An error occurred in the secure channel support"`. Meanwhile, I will have to study his code because I'm not familiar with the objects in his code. Also, it's a little bit advanced for me. When I run the code it created a text file, which contains response headers, I believe, and an HTML file that contains redirection instruction to the homepage.

Comment: Cool :-) I grabbed the set-cookie from the request headers to try and pass on but didn't work for me :-(